# DIVS resize when address bar hides on Mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm designing a website and I used sections with all the same class
all height:100vh, it works fine on a browser but the problems it's on phones;

now every time I scroll down divs scale up in order to fill the space of the address bar... I've try everything... 
please can someone help me with this... thanks

www.nachopalaciosdg.com.ar/ejemplo/index.html

Comment: I think you're probably out of luck; All the browser vendors do different, hacky things to get their silly addressbar shenanigans to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the viewport height changes when the bar hides. Can you set a max-height value or use JS to define the height on document ready?

Something like:

```
document.getElementById("myID").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
```

Or with jQuery you could easily target all elements with the same class:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $(".myClass").height(window.innerHeight);
}
```

I don't think that you can avoid the problem with CSS as long as you want to use the full viewport height for each element on your site.